# how to apply ellipsis for dynamic content of multiple lines and hide for single line in css for chrome ,IE10 and above

Tags: css

I tried the following

```
card_line_clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

But it is not working in IE 10 and above

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsis on multiple line is difficult to accomplish with 100% CSS. There is an interesting article about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) which links to a [100% CSS method](http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/) that looks pretty cumbersome to use.

It is much easier to settle for a javascript solution. If you are using jQuery, you can try [jquery-ellipsis](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/jquery-ellipsis) which works great.

If you want to keep 3 lines of text and ellipsis after that, you would do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.yourcontentclass').ellipsis({maxLine: 3});
})
```